# How to create next and previous for a details page using c# and an id in XML?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, xml

I have this XML, i'm busy with an advertisement and i created two pages, one for all the products in my XML and one is details page for each product. Every product has an URL like this ("details.aspx?uId=3332"). I want to create two buttons (next & previous) inside the details page so that when you click on next, it will look through the xml and find the next product with the ulId that comes right after the one that is being displayed or (to change the url to details.aspx?uId=(the next uId to find (which in this case is will be 3333))).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <root>
        <advertentie>
        <uId>3332</uId>
        <auto>
            <merk>GX-TM</merk>
            <carroserie>Sedan</carroserie>
        </auto>
        <afbeeldingen>
            <laatsUpdate>10.00</laatsUpdate>
  <FotoGroot>http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/63300/63366/63366_head_lg.gif</FotoGroot>
  <FotoGroot>https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsXe7qqTisxV9_XpRGtY64fWMllpSAZwSIDzqRMLp4EVgJwStO</FotoGroot>
</afbeeldingen>
</advertentie>
 <advertentie>
<uId>3333</uId>
<auto>
  <merk>MB-Maybach</merk>
  <carroserie>Sedan</carroserie>
</auto>
<afbeeldingen>
  <laatsUpdate>11.00</laatsUpdate>
  <FotoGroot>http://static.robbreport.com/sites/default/files/mercdes-s600-maybach.jpg</FotoGroot>
  <FotoGroot>https://images.cdn.autocar.co.uk/sites/autocar.co.uk/files/styles/gallery_slide/public/merc-s-class-road-test-017.jpg?itok=pF_TCkMU</FotoGroot>
</afbeeldingen>
</advertentie>
<advertentie>
<uId>3334</uId>
<auto>
  <merk>Royal-Gold</merk>
  <carroserie>Stationwagen</carroserie>
</auto>
<afbeeldingen>
  <laatsUpdate>12.00</laatsUpdate>
  <FotoGroot>http://iluvesports.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/royal-car-collection-1-600x369.jpg</FotoGroot>
  <FotoGroot>https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RDe3ZvTv5AQ/maxresdefault.jpg</FotoGroot>
</afbeeldingen>
</advertentie>
</root>
```

Comment: Do you need to obtain nextId through ajax when clicking the button or it is available when generating the page?

I think it`s better to parse XML just once, get the info for the current product and two ids, next and previous, and then pass them to the page.

Comment: @Atchitutchuk i added ajax and javascript because, i made a couple of research and many of the answers were based on ajax and/of javascript but as for me, i'm open for any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;




namespace WindowsFormsApplication29
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        List<XElement> advertentie = null;
        int advertentieIndex = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            advertentie = doc.Descendants("advertentie").ToList();
            textBoxUserId.Text = (string)advertentie[advertentieIndex].Element("uId");
        }



        private void buttonPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (advertentieIndex != 0)
            {
                advertentieIndex -= 1;
                textBoxUserId.Text = (string)advertentie[advertentieIndex].Element("uId");
            }

        }

        private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (advertentieIndex != advertentie.Count - 1)
            {
                advertentieIndex += 1;
                textBoxUserId.Text = (string)advertentie[advertentieIndex].Element("uId");
            }

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you have done here but the xml i posted was a part (demo) of my intire project, i have a couple of uId like 8562, 7745, and so on, how am i going to do that?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to check the next uId under advertentie  (just speaking from a beginners perspective)?

Comment: The code looks for all tags advertentie (descendants) and puts them into the list.  UserID is a child of advertentie.  The code I posted displays all three ID.

Comment: There are two reason I wrote the code this way 1)  Element("uid") will search all the child elements so order isn't important (don't like next which depends on order). 2) Using "Descendants("Advertentie") allows you to get the userid and all other properties.  Not just the UserId.

Comment: Ok thank you I'm going try, thank you also for your explanation

Comment: but one question, how can i change from textbox to page url?

Comment: it is a string : "details.aspx?uId=3332".  string url = string.Format( "details.aspx?uId={0}", (string)advertentie[advertentieIndex].Element("uId"));

Comment: Don't use just have to Navigate to the url?  How are you current getting to each webpage?

Comment: I have tried and there is no errors but it is also NOT showing the next or the previous

Comment: You need to debug problem.  Put break points and make sure it is executing the code inside the click methods.  Also make sure the List<XElement> advertentie contains data.